# Why can't Scala 3 summon a Conversion instance from a Scala 2 implicit conversion?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-3

Why can't Scala 3 summon a `Conversion` instance from a Scala 2 implicit conversion?

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class A(name: String)

case class B(name: String)

implicit def aToB(a: A): B = B(a.name)

// Works
summon[A => B]

// Fails with: No given instance of type Conversion[Playground.A, Playground.B] was found for parameter x of method summon in object Predef
summon[Conversion[A, B]]
```

I am writing a Scala 3 library and I want to use the new `Conversion` however it fails to find an instance where the conversion is coming from a third party library that is a Scala 3 library but still using the old implicit conversion style. Now it seems that for my library to be compatible I need to expect the old style. This seems like a slippery slope backwards to where everything is stuck on the old style. Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably can define the `Conversion` yourself and delegate it to the existing `implicit def`

Comment: Well not me, the users of my library would have to do that which is an annoying burden for them. Better off if my library expects an implicit conversion function instead of `Conversion`.

Comment: The friction around `Conversion` is extremely intentional because it's almost always a bad idea that causes pain. In general you only want to use `Conversion` when two types are *truly* isomorphic, ie you can do `A=>B` and `B=A` arbitrarily and without losing information. Normal api design should not be using them

Comment: That's not true. `Conversion` has minimal friction and certainly does not need to be isomorphic. A lot of APIs benefit from it. It doesn't even have to be doing the conversion implicitly, it can often be used as any other type class would. The change in Scala 3 is to encourage us to be more explicit that a conversion is desired. The lack of compatibility between `Conversion` and `implicit def` just means library authors who want conversions will stick with `implicit def`.